# What are o(n) numbers?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I am reading an economic theoretical paper. In one of this paper` s propositions it is said that : *"if $k_n$ and $M_n$ are $o(n)$ then ..."* .

But it does not hint that what are $o(n)$ numbers exactly. Also google search does not lead to a respond to this question. Does any body help me by telling what are usually the $o(n)$ numbers in math?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $k_n=o(n)$ if $\frac {k_n} n \to 0$.

Comment: See [Little o notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html#:~:text=The%20symbol%20%2C%20pronounced%20%22little%2D,behavior%20of%20a%20given%20function.)

Comment: There is no such thing as an $o(n)$ number, but there are $o(n)$ *sequences*

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442252/898649

Comment: When I do a Google search for “o(n)”, the first seven hits all explain that notation.

Comment: @tparker, true, but OP probably thought $o(n)$ was referring to a class of numbers (as evidenced by the title and the content of this question) and looked up "$o(n)$ numbers". That search on Google doesn't return anything useful.